# How to gather files accross branches inside specific folders which were never deployed?

Tags: scripting, mercurial, versioning, sourcetree, kiln

We are developing a .NET Webforms application using SQL Server. To version the project, we use Mercurial, Kiln and SourceTree. There are several branches, two branches stand out of those, namely **live** and **dev**. All the other branches are either hotfix or feature branches. We use RoundHouse to run our scripts upon deploy on the live database.

However, we, developers play with a daily copy of that database. Whenever a deploy is issued, database scripts in a specific folder's subfolders are executed on the live database, if and only if they were not deployed yet. So far so good. However, whenever we start a new day, everyone has to execute his/her undeployed scripts. I would like to make that automatic. For this purpose I intend to write a small code/shell which will run the undeployed scripts in the specific folder and subfolders in the order they were created (the files have a utc date in their names, but they have a create date as files as well). And then the event which creates the daily copy will be enhanced with this.

The problem is that I do not know how could I gather the undeployed file paths in all branches. If this is impossible, then the second-best solution would be to run only those scripts which were not merged into the **live** branch. This is second-best, due to the fact that this implies a policy change along with something new to watch out for.

Comment: So basically you want to list every file in a specific directory in every branch where the file is not in the live branch? Then checkout each file and run it?

Comment: @arjabbar, something like that. To be precise, my intention is to gather all the undeployed scripts file in that folder from any branches and execute them. This could be done in a folder which is in .hgignore, for example

Comment: How do you define exactly which script has been deployed or not?

Comment: @arjabbar at deploy I can store the file names deployed somewhere. Let us suppose that I have a small .NET application that knows what is deployed to simplify this.